# JPA problemas al persistir en cascada una subclase

Tags: java, jpa

Tengo las siguientes clases

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "personas")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@ClassExtractor(PersonExtractor.class)
abstract public class Persona implements AbstractEntity<Long>, Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1584956755146844000L;      

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id_persona")
  private long id;

  ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "personas_fisicas")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id_persona")
public class PersonaFisica extends Persona {

   ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "legajos_empleados")
public class LegajoEmpleado implements AbstractEntity<Long>, Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 4528140042468695166L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @Column(name = "id_legajo_empleado")
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "empleado", referencedColumnName = "id_persona", nullable = false)
   private PersonaFisica empleado;

   ...
}
```

El problema es que cuando persisto una instancia de LegajoEmpleado que tiene en el atributo "empleado" una instancia de PersonaFisica que no se encuentra registrada en la base de datos solamente se genera un registro para Persona y no para PersonaFisica y cuando intenta guardar el legajo en la bd se produce una violación de la FK.

```
Detallado:   INSERT INTO personas (celular, cliente, codigo_postal, direccion, email, localidad, observaciones, pais, proveedor, provincia, telefono) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [, false, , , , , , , false, , ]
Detallado:   select lastval()
Detallado:   INSERT INTO legajos_empleados (fecha_inicio_categoria, fecha_inicio_empresa, fecha_inicio_periodo, legajo_interno, OBSERVACIONES, valor_hora_adicional, valor_hora_escalafon, categoria_actual, empleado) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [2018-03-30, 2018-03-15, 2018-03-15, , , 0.0, 0.0, 2, 19]
Detallado:   SELECT 1
Advertencia:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: inserción o actualización en la tabla «legajos_empleados» viola la llave foránea «legajos_empleados_empleado_fkey»
Detail: La llave (empleado)=(19) no está presente en la tabla «personas_fisicas».
Error Code: 0
```

Edición:

Tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La relación OneToOne tienes que hacerla directamente con la entidad Persona, ya que es la entidad poseedora de la relación y la que tiene el id. Luego puedes pasarle la entidad PersonaFisica o, si lo necesitases, cualquiera que herede de Persona.

Es decir, en la entidad LegajoEmpleado la relación seria la siguiente:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "empleado", referencedColumnName = "id_persona", nullable = false)
private Persona empleado;
```

Y luego en tu código puedas hacer perfectamente esto:

```
empleado = new PersonaFisica();
empleado.set... // los que sean
entityManager.persist(legajoEmpleado);
```

Comment: No me funciona porque la fk está con la tabla "personas_fisicas". Voy a editar la pregunta para subir una imagen con las tablas.

Comment: Estás leyendo PersonaFisica antes de hacer el persist, esa FK con valor 19 existe en la tabla personas o en personas_fisicas? ¿Puedes poner el código de como haces el persist?

Comment: Existe en la tabla personas, que por lo que entiendo es del insert anterior. Una vez que eclipselink hace el insert en personas debería hacer otro en personas_fisicas pero en lugar de eso pasa directamente a legajos_empleados.

Comment: Las tablas las has creado con eclipselink, verdad? No hace falta que las crees a mano. Aún así creo que el problema sigue estando en lo que comento, la relación de  la tabla y la entidad legajoEmpleados debería ser con personas y la propia base de datos te la réplica en la otra tabla personas_fisicas.

Comment: Las tablas las hice a mano, en realidad use el sql generado por MySQL Workbench y lo adapte para Postgresql. Ya cambíe PersonaFisica por Persona pero falla porque la fk esta con el campo "id_persona" de la tabla "personas_fisicas". Tendría que cambiarla manualmente para que sea con el "id_persona" de la tabla "personas". Si hago eso supongo que no tendría problemas pero ¿me va a registrar solamente los datos de la "persona"? es decir, voy a peder los datos de los atributos de PersonaFisica ya que no se hace el correspondiente INSERT.

Comment: Pero para que te lo pase como persona fisica tienes que hacer a ese atributo que llamas empleado un Persona empleado = new PersonaFisica() así tienes todos sus datos y puedes hacer sus sets como te puse en la segunda parte de la respuesta. Si empleado es un ojeto de tipo Persona peudes hacer los sets de persona fisica que necesites haciendo un cast poniendo ((PersonaFisca)empleado).setDePersonaFisica(...). Y al pasarle una entidad del tipo personaFisica esos datos te los pondrá en la tabla correspondiente de la BBDD, es decir, te hará INSERT en las dos tablas.

Comment: Funciona. Modifiqué la fk para que sea con la tabla "personas". Los insert se hacen en este orden:

insert personas
insert legajos_empleados
insert personas_fisicas 

Por eso el error en la fk. No sé si exite forma de indicarle a eclipselink que haga el insert personas_fisicas luego del insert personas. Al no estar la fk con la tabla "personas_fisicas" supongo que por algún error se puede asignar una persona jurídica por ejemplo, pero creo que con un trigger lo puedo solucionar.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Más que hacer un trigger deberias controlarlo en la aplicación para que no se asignen personas de otro tipo con alguna regla de negocio, pero si, un trigger es una opción. Me alegro que haya sido de ayuda!